# Align number in word table based on first digit not minus sign

Tags: ms-word

I am trying to align numbers in a column in a table in word. However, when I try to left align them, negative numbers (and numbers with a < sign) are aligned differently than positive numbers. E.g.

```
-1.234
1.234
<0.001
```

I would like to have them aligned like this:

```
-1.234
 1.234
<0.001
```

Spaces or tabs havent helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Decimal Tab to align your numbers.

[image]

Just click on  `Top Rular` to add a tab and double click on it. It will prompt `Tabs` Dialog box, select `Decimal` from `Alignment` section.

Comment: Thanks, I never new this, it worked.